# Best way to create categories 

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, xml

I want to give use the opportunity to create categories

for example:

```
Web Programming
  Microsoft
    ASP.NET
      C#
      VB
  PHP

System Programming
  C#
    Console
    WinForms
    WPF
  VB
```

I have databse with Product Table which i want to connect to categories.

Please advice how i can solve this problem.

Does i use sql or xml or something other?

P.S i dont know how many categories and sub categories would be.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question: How to store categories tree in the database? Or you don't know how to provide access to them from c# code? Or what? Please, describe your problem more accuracy.

Comment: In WPF the best control designed to display hierarchical data is `TreeView`. Search around the internet for examples that use this control. One of them: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a PK FK relationship.  If a product can be in more than one category then you use a many to many table

```
Category:
ID PK 
Name 

Product:
ID PK
Name 

Cat2Prod
IDcat PK, FK to Category.ID
IDprod PK, FK to Product.ID


Select Category.Name, Product.Name 
From Cat2Prod 
Join Category on Category.ID = Cat2Prod.IDcat 
Join Category on Product.ID = Cat2Prod.IDprod
where ... 


if it is not many to many then just 


Product:
ID PK
Name
IDcat FK to Category.ID
```